# How can I - as administrator - change a standard user's password in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, password-management

Surprised I didn't find this question already ...

My kid tried to set a password for their standard account on a Windows 10 system. Unfortunately the log in fails. I can get in as admin, but going through the settings interface only seems to allow me to set the admin password. My web search feels like it is leading me down the proverbial rabbit hole, telling me to go to the command prompt and type

> net user "USERNAME" "NEW_PASSWORD"

However, I get a System Error 5 (which is "Access denied" from what I found on the web).

So, how can I overwrite another user's password from a Windows 10 admin account?

Comment: You are not running as an Administrator [How to open elevated command prompt in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose "Run as administrator" when you start Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click your Start menu and select the **Command Prompt (admin)**

[image]

or you can also go to user accounts and reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 10 Pro, you can manage your user accounts from within the Management Console. Open the management console by opening the run command "Win + R" and entering "mmc". Press enter to open. Once MMC opens, go "File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> Local users and groups -> Finish -> Ok". From here, the MMC will list all the active groups and users on the machine, under their own categories. You can find the user you want to change, right-click on it and go "Reset Password", or similar. Hope this works for you, as an alternative method.

PLEASE NOTE: this is **ONLY** for Windows 10 Pro - this will not work on Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

If the account your kid used is a Microsoft account, you need to reset it online via [Microsoft webpage](https://account.live.com/password/reset).

If it's a local account, press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> keyboard shortcut. When the WinX menu opens, select **Command Prompt (Admin)**. At the Command Prompt, type the following command to reset the password of any local user:

**net user user_name  new_password**

**Note:** replace user_name with the name of your kid's account, and new_password with your desired password.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this answer here but open the control panel and navigate to:

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Manage Accounts

Select the user account to manage.

Click change password and follow the directions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change the account password:

1. Type `lusrmgr.msc` in the search box in the Start menu or on the taskbar, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. If prompted by UAC, click/tap on `Yes`.
3. Click/tap on `Users` in the left pane, select a local account (e.g. `Brink_2`) in the middle pane, and click/tap on `More Actions` and `Set Password` in the right pane.
4. Click/tap on `Proceed` to confirm.
5. Type in a new password, and click/tap on `OK`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quEEY.png)

**Credit**: [10 Free Tools to Change Windows Password](https://www.passmoz.com/best-windows-password-recovery-tool.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Looks like you omitted the screenshot. Just upload it to [imgur](//imgur.com/), then [edit your post](//superuser.com/posts/1336911/edit) and add in the link. A user with higher reputation will then inline the screenshot for you.